# Marshal a variable-size array of structures nested within a structure

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I need to pass a structure containing an array of structures that is of an unknown length at compile-time.

I've found examples of how to Marshal variable-size arrays of primitives with Marshal.Copy and fixed-size arrays of structures using an IntPtr[] array and Marshal.StructureToPtr, but that uses MarshalAs(UnamangedType.ByValArray) in the structure definition which requires the SizeConst parameter.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do. In the C dll I have a structure with a sine wave defintion

```
typedef struct sinWave
{
    double amp;         /*  sine wave amplitude     */
    double t;           /*  time                    */
    double period;      /*  oscilation period       */
    double omega;       /*  phase angle             */
} sinWave;
```

and a structure that can hold multiple waves

```
typedef struct sinWaveAdd
{
    sinWave *waves;     /*  array of sine waves     */
    int len;            /*  length of the array     */
} sinWaveAdd;
```

This gets used in wave superposition function with the following prototype

```
__declspec( dllexport ) double calculateMult( sinWaveAdd *in )
```

In c# I have a sinWave struct that works well on its own

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class sinWaveStruct
{
    public double amp;      /*  sine wave amplitude */
    public double t;        /*  time                */
    public double period;   /*  oscillation period  */
    public double omega;    /*  phase angle         */
}

public sinWaveStruct(double ampP, double tP, double periodP, double omegaP)
{
    amp = ampP;
    t = tP;
    period = periodP;
    omega = omegaP;
}
}
```

but I don't really know how to construct the larger structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class sinWaveAddClass
{
    public IntPtr waves;        /*  array of sinWaveStruct waves    */
    public int len;             /*  length of array */
}
```

since I need the number of waves to not be constant.

Is there a way to Marshal the waves array to sinWaveStruct[], IntPtr, or IntPtr[] without having a constant size array?

Comment: @HansPassant Surely easier just to pin the array?

Comment: It is.  Perhaps a warning to the OP that his C code should not store pointer is appropriate.  Sine waves take time to be played back ;)

Comment: @Hans These look like they are processed into a single value which is returned

Answer (score 1):

I'd declare the structures as `struct`. That makes them value types rather than reference types. Important when you want to make arrays of them. Especially as `sinWave` is blittable.

```
public struct sinWaveStruct
{
    public double amp;      /*  sine wave amplitude */
    public double t;        /*  time                */
    public double period;   /*  oscillation period  */
    public double omega;    /*  phase angle         */
}

public struct sinWaveAdd
{
    public IntPtr waves;        /*  array of sinWaveStruct waves    */
    public int len;             /*  length of array */
}
```

The function you import is:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double calculateMult(ref sinWaveAdd in);
```

So then create and populate an array of `sinWaveAdd`:

```
sinWaveStruct[] arr = new sinWaveStruct[len];
// populate arr
```

Then pin the array and obtain its address:

```
GCHandle arrHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    sinWaveAdd in;
    in.waves = arrHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    in.len = len;
    double retval = calculateMult(ref in);
}
finally
{
    arrHandle.Free();
}
```